# How do I extend a PC to a Microsoft Surface?

Tags: windows, extended-desktop

I have a HTPC running Windows 10 and I have a Microsoft Surface also running Windows 10. I would like to use the Surface to control my HTPC. How do I extend my HTPC to my Surface or mirror the HTPC onto the Surface? Preferably, this connection would be persistent and I wouldn't have to reconnect the two computers every day.

Comment: Remote control software like TeamViewer (third party) or Remote Desktop (built in) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote desktop connection to do this. You can only use remote desktop connection if you are on the same network as the computer you are trying to connect to. I have used remote desktop connection extensively to connect to my server and the application works perfectly. If you need to connect to your PC outside of the network I would recommend using a application like team viewer.